# Pandas : Extract the IDs with the similar names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe shown below:

```
my_id       my_date  full_name
1602    2019-07-18  TIM DAVID ODE
6243    2016-11-11  ToNI Jol DOPER
6243    2016-11-11  TONI DOPER
3487    2019-11-02  Michael WILLIAMSON
9797    2020-10-13  Louise Groundor
9293    2020-10-12  Tim Ode
7865    2020-10-15  Toni Jol K. DOPER
```

I want to compare the names of the customer and identify the ones which are similar but belongs to a different my_id

Expected Output :

```
my_id       my_date  full_name        matched_id   matched_date    mathed_name
1602    2019-07-18  TIM DAVID ODE      9293       2020-10-12       Tim Ode
6243    2016-11-11  ToNI Jol DOPER     7865       2020-10-15       Toni Jol K. DOPER
6243    2016-11-11  TONI DOPER         7865       2020-10-15       Toni Jol K. DOPER
9293    2020-10-12  Tim Ode            1602       2019-07-18       TIM DAVID ODE
7865    2020-10-15  Toni Jol K. DOPER  6243       2016-11-11       ToNI Jol DOPER 
7865    2020-10-15  Toni Jol K. DOPER  6243       2016-11-11       TONI DOPER
```

I am planning to use `difflib.get_close_matches( cutoff=0.8)`  with a cuttoff of `0.8` but I am also not sure if this is the best way to do this.

Comment: It depends on if it might be misspellings in names like "tonY" instead of "tonI".

Comment: @Raibek . that's fine. I am just looking at closer similarity here and based on that I will define my cutoff.

Comment: One way is to use package fuzzywuzzy for fuzzy string matching, but I suppose you'd need some text pre-processing depending on your requirment